# has_many :through query with both values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

Let's say I have:

```
class Post
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  has_many :taggings
end
```

Notice there's no :include. Now say I want to retrieve all taggings and tags in the same query. How could I do that?

I'm looking for something like:

```
taggings = post.taggings(:include => tags) # doesn't work
```

I could make a custom query or add a third association to Post with an :include, but neither feels right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `includes` on the association proxy as you would with the model class:

```
taggings = post.taggings.includes(:tag)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the syntax I was after.